# How to create different session for different users in Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: asp.net, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am new to `Microsoft Bot Framework`.I have created a bot using `Microsoft Bot Framework`. How do I create a session so that the `variebles` added to the controller is individual specific. Currently the problem I am facing is whenever multiple users are chatting with the bot, the values in the `variebles` are getting over written thus giving wrong values to the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you referred
 https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/stateapi.html

In my project am using simple code to store session value for a user based on his device.

```
StateClient sc = activity.GetStateClient();
        userData.SetProperty<string>("MyDetails", < some value >);
        // Save BotUserData
        await sc.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
        // Get BotUserData 
        BotData userData = await sc.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
```

So, you can store values to individual user.