# Create and handle multiple session for multiple users while making web socket connection in Microsoft Bot Builder

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am new to Microsoft Bot Framework .I have created a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework. How do I create a session for individual user. Currently the problem I am facing is whenever multiple users are creating connection, the values in the variables are getting over written thus giving wrong values to the users.

Here is the code

```
if (turnContext.activity.text === 'CCP') {
const url = await this.connectToAgent(members);
const initialMessage = {
    topic: "aws/subscribe",
    content: {
        topics: ["aws/chat"]
    }
};
ws = new WebSocket(url[1]);
ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(initialMessage));
});
await turnContext.sendActivity("Please wait while we connect you to an agent.");
conversationReferences[currentUser] = TurnContext.getConversationReference(turnContext.activity);
adapter = turnContext.adapter;
ws.addEventListener('message', async function (event) {
    const msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
    
});
let sendChatHistory = (function() {
    let executed = false;
    return function() {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            const param = {
                ConnectionToken: connectionToken, /* required */
                Content: sendHistory, /* required */
                ContentType: 'text/plain', /* required */
            };
            connectparticipant.sendMessage(param,async function (err, data) {
                chatHistory = '';
                sendHistory = '';
                if (err) {
                    errorMsg = "Error while sending a message";
                }
            });
        }
    };
})();
sendChatHistory();   
}
```

Comment: are you looking same?-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615088/how-to-create-different-session-for-different-users-in-microsoft-bot-framework

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) we have the procedure of `StateClient` where we can give separate activity holder for individual users. This works when we are creating multiple users with multiple connections.

```
StateClient sc = activity.GetStateClient();
        userData.SetProperty<string>("MyDetails", < some value >);
        // How to save the BotUserData 
        await sc.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
        // Getting User data from bot 
        BotData userData = await sc.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
```

As this is a **parallel operation**, the method **Async** is required to get the data of user **simultaneously**.